# Why does the binomial distribution become more symmetrical as number of trials increase?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image: See this image from my textbook]

(Referring to image above) My textbook says that if $p\neq{0.5}$ then it will be skewed. That makes sense as it's more likely you'll lose when p=0.3, in this case. However, the textbook also states that as $n$ increases, the binomial distribution graph will become more symmetrical. How does that work?

Comment: This is essentially because of the central limit theorem. The sum of samples from any "nice enough" distribution becomes more like a symmetric normal distribution as the sample size increases.